# clientWidth "lying", unable to determine actual width of element

Tags: javascript, html, dom

```
<div style="width: 50px;">
  <div id="theElement" style="position: relative; left 25px;">textMuchLongerThan50[</div>
</div>
```

**document.getElementById("theElement").clientWidth** always returns 50, which is width of the parent element, while it is obvious the element's content is much wider

(The element itself actually has this width, but I need to know its "natural" width, i.e. width of its content.)

Experiencing this behaviour in Chrome and IE. If anoyne knew how to determine the actual dimensions of a relatively positioned DIV residing in another DIV with pre-set/limited width...?

Comment: I think jQuery's `.width()` can work around a lot of these problems. Is using it an option? (Edit: scratch that, it's lying as well)

Comment: @Pekka웃 It actually worked for me. Netiher `clientWidth` nor `scrollWidth` worked, but `width()` actually did the trick on `jQuery Combobox`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are interested in [**scrollWidth**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.scrollWidth): [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/yHjre/1)

Comment: damn me, i swear i tested all three: clientWidth, offsetWidth and scrollWidth... thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is because it's a block element, and it is actually taking its width from its parent. The text inside it is overflowing outside of its container, but isn't affecting the container's actual width.

You can prove this by adding a `border` style to the inner `<div>`.

You can cause the element to take its width from the width of the text by changing its display type.

If you set it to `display:inline-block;`, it will report the correct width.

And if you add a `border` now, you'll notice that it has changed as well.

Comment: i know all this (i guess the note about Chrome and IE made it look otherwise)... i have been playing with this for far too long... thanks anyways